# latex symbol for "if and only if"

Tags: symbols, math-operators, logic

In LaTeX the symbol for material implication is produced by `$\to$`, but for [biconditional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if) ?

Comment: Isn't it `\iff`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: @LudovicC., no \iff is the symbol with two lines. I nedd the symbol with one line..!!

Comment: @LudovicC. there is also a version without the think double arrow. It might seem redundant but for people working on mathematical logic its important to distinguish which ones are part of the formal language being developed and which ones are part of the meta-language proving the logic being developed in question.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

LaTeX defines `\to` as `\rightarrow`:

```
\let\to\rightarrow % fontmath.ltx
```

The other direction is `\gets`:

```
\let\gets\leftarrow
```

For `\leftrightarrow` you can define your own command, e.g. `\biconditional`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\biconditional\leftrightarrow
\begin{document}
\[ A \to B \biconditional C \gets D \]

\[ A \rightarrow B \leftrightarrow C \leftarrow D \]
\[ A \longrightarrow B \longleftrightarrow C \longleftarrow D \]

\[ A \Rightarrow B \Leftrightarrow C \Leftarrow D \]
\[ A \Longrightarrow B \Longleftrightarrow C \Longleftarrow D \]
\[ B \iff C \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- `\iff` adds some extra space (from `fontmath.ltx`):

  ```
  \DeclareRobustCommand\iff{\;\Longleftrightarrow\;}
  ```
- The example also shows some other arrow variants.

Comment: thanks.. but I use \biconditional and I have "Undefined control sequence"

Comment: @Soviet: Then you have missed the line `\let\biconditional\leftrightarrow`.

Comment: if I use \leftrightarrow it is ok..

Comment: which one most closely resembles the style of `\implies`?

Comment: @joseville Package `amsmath` defines `\implies` as `\Longrightarrow` with some additional horizontal space (`\;`) around the symbol: `\newcommand{\implies}{\DOTSB\;\Longrightarrow\;}`

Answer (score 21):

You can use `\Leftrightarrow` or `\Longleftrightarrow`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$ \Leftrightarrow \Longleftrightarrow $
\end{document}
```

[image]

You might want to also bookmark this: https://oeis.org/wiki/List_of_LaTeX_mathematical_symbols

Comment: @ChristosLytras The link works for me. Please update your comment.

Answer (score 10):

**Double line:**

- `\iff` (= `\Leftrightarrow`) or
- `\longLeftrightarrow` or
- `\xLeftrightarrow` (extensible, load the `mathtools` package)

**Single line:**

- `\leftrightarrow` or
- `\longleftrightarrow` or
- `\xleftrightarrow` (extensible, load the `mathtools` package)

Comment: Isn't it `\Longleftrightarrow`?